# Android commons-net FTP File Upload

Tags: android

I am using the following code snippet in my android app to transfer a file through FTP. Already using passive mode with binary file mode set. Right now the code is as is and the filename is hardcoded for a file that exists on my phone. I connect on Wifi and wish the file to be transferred to the FTP server on the mentioned address. Have tested the code to work over another machine on the same network. The ADT-eclipse emulators dont work for this, and my Xperia Ray ST18i updated to Android 4.0 is not getting detected as a valid device on being connected. I have imported the commons-net-3.2.jar successfully in ADT and copy the .apk file on my phone to check while connected on Wifi. But, the transfer is not working. It would be great if I could get pointers on debugging this either in the emulator or on my phone. Thanks.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
public class test
{
  private static String server = "<valid-ip-address>";
  private static String username = "<valid-user>";
  private static String password = "password";
  private static String fileLocation = "<valid-file>";
  private static String fileName = "<valid-file>";


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    FTPClient f = new FTPClient();
    f.connect(server);
    f.login(username, password);
    f.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    f.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileLocation); 
    f.storeFile(fileName, is);
    f.disconnect();
    is.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** If you have tested this code before, then it means that it was working earlier, but still i would like to throw lime light on few issues that must be in the check list.

**-** Check you have the `Internet Permission` in your manifest.

**-** Check your `file location` is correct.

**-** I have you have added the commons-ftp jar in the project path, and its not throwing any compilation error (I know this is silly but still check it.).

**-** Please see that you are calling the **ftp code on Non-UI thread**, by using `Thread` with `Handler` or `AsyncTask`.